# Ofstream does not write in file

Tags: c++, file, fstream, ofstream

I have problem with ofstream. I have program, whitch must write in file info (langulange settings). If i start with VS 2019 Debug or Release all is OK, but whith installer ofstream does not want to work. After installing program read from file, but dont want to write. Can you help?

```
int langulange = 1;
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ifstream file("config.txt");
if (!file.is_open()) {
    ofstream out("config.txt");
    out << langulange;
    out.close();
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: You realize both streams (the apparently unused and pointless `file` read-stream, and the `out` write-stream) are opening *the same file*, right? A file called `config.txt` in the current working directory of your process?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code, it is working as expected.  Please check the working directory to see the file.

Comment: @foragerDev there are not file in directory

Comment: @WhiozCraig i try to write file.close();  after ifstream file("config.txt"); but there was no result